# JSoup - Extracting image url from attributes

Tags: java, android, jsoup

How to extract image url from:

```
<div class="img" style="background-image: url(images/rols/roll_1.png);"></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please describe what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution of the OP works of course, but it is generally not a great idea to use the attribute matching for class matching. The reason is, that an element may have many classes and they may appear in any order. So a matching for

```
Node.select("div[class=img]").attr("style")
```

will only match if the class is exactly and only  `img`. The following element would not be found:

```
<div class="highlight img overview" style="background-image: url(images/rols/roll_1.png);"></div>
```

A better way is to use the CSS class selector, where `.img` specifies the class. Note the dot, it belongs to the selector:

```
Node.select("div.img").attr("style")
```

If you need to match more than one class you can concatenate:

```
Node.select("div.img.highlight").attr("style")
```

Comment: oh, thank you! it's my first time using jsoup. Do I need change all the selectors like "div[class=name]", "div[class=count]" to "div.name" and "div.count"?

Comment: you don't need to if it works for you the other way. It is just a bit less flexible. If you control the original HTML it is no problem at all, since you can change things accordingly. If you parse content that is not from you, then you are probably better off changing to the more general class selector style.

Comment: content is not mine, I will do that more flexible. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
Node.select("div[class=img]").attr("style")
```

gives me "background-image: url(images/rols/roll_1.png);"

Thanks to all!